# PIC EEPROM after re-programming

Tags: pic, eeprom

I was trying to get my EEPROM read/write working on my PIC.

I first programmed a write cycle, and then reprogrammed it to read it out. (To avoid writing every time I start the program/pic)

But I luckily found out that re-programming your PIC causes EEPROM to get... changed?
I found a way to fix this, by using the setting "Preserve EEPROM".

My questions on this are:

- Does "Preserve EEPROM" write the EEPROM everytime you program your chip? (So re-programming a million times will break EEPROM theoretically)
- What value is EEPROM after it's programmed... `(val != 0xFF)` returns `true` Can I say it's corrupted after programming, or does it get a default value I could check on?

Using: (though it's more theoretical)

- MPLAB X IDE
- PICKIT3
- PIC18F66K22

Comment: Typically the flash used for the program memory will wear out before the EEPROM does.

Comment: I'm, indeed, using a PICKit3 (added it to the question).
And I didn't know that, but will it theoretically add up? Or well, does "Preserve EEPROM" mean it re-writes the EEPROM?

Comment: I've always understood the "preserve EEPROM" setting to mean that the EEPROM is left alone and ignored, not that it gets read out, erased and then re-programmed...

Comment: Hmm, I somehow thought my output window echo'd something like:
Programming areas: `Flash (0x00 to 0xFF) EEPROM`. But I'm unable to replicate this. Using preserve EEPROM does not have any disadvantages?

What about the value of the EEPROM after programming (withouth preserve), is it 0xFF or `undefined`?

Comment: `The following memory area(s) will be programmed:
program memory: start address = 0x0, end address = 0x347f
configuration memory
EEData memory`

Programmer output when programming the chip...
...for me it looks like it's 'rewriting' the EEPROM. As it says `area(s) will be programmed` ~ `EEData memory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Preserve EEPROM' suggests EEPROM content is not changed when chip is reprogrammed. I am not sure if it means the memory is not touched at all during the process. I might involve Pickit reading the data EEPROM, erasing the whole chip, programming the chip, then writing the data EEPROM with the old values.

If you are using Programmer-to-Go mode of Pickit, preserving EEPROM may not work like this.

If you have the CPD (Data EEPROM code-protected) fuse set, then Pickit can't read the EEPROM. You can work around this with 'Erase Configuration Bits' command.

Also a discussion at Microchip suggested that 'Erase all before programming' option overrides the 'Preserve EEPROM' setting.

Comment: Still not sure if it does re-write it. But it actually doesn't matter that much, as the flash memory is probably worn out earlier.